# Installing MySQLi with Apache 2 and PHP 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, mysqli

I'm really stuck on this I've been searching for hours...

I recently installed an Apache server on a remote Ubuntu box for my website and I wanted to get started with PHP and MySQL. MySQL is installed and running. PHP installed fine, that works, but I can't figure out how to enable the MySQL extension. I've already done `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` and/or `sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd` but neither of those seemed to actually install anything, at least according to my Apache server. When I run `php -m` I see mysql, mysqli, and mysqlnd. I've also tried uncommenting the lines for loading the extensions in the Apache `php.ini` file but none of the `mysql.so` or `mysqli.so` or whatever exist in the default extension directory. There is another PHP extensions directory with those files in it, but when I tried pointing my Apache server to that extension directory, I got errors saying this:

```
/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: core_globals in Unknown on line 0
```

I've tried everything I've seen so far and nothing has worked. That error was the closest I got. Any help is appreciated.

Also here's my `phpinfo()` output: http://pastebin.com/VM8kyrKV

I also get this when I run `sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`:

```
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqlnd for cli SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqlnd for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for cli SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysql for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for cli SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module mysqli for apache2 SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for cli SAPI
php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_mysql for apache2 SAPI
```

Which seems to look good but it's still not working... I can't find any mysql module files anywhere except the ones for CLI PHP.

**Edit:**
Long story short, don't compile your own binaries... I started over only using `apt-get` to install things and everything just worked.

Answer (score 2):

> I've already done sudo apt-get install php5-mysql and/or sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd but neither of those seemed to actually install anything, at least according to my Apache server.

Your output from `phpinfo()` shows both the mysql and mysqlnd modules are active. This suggests the install was successful and you just need to uncomment the line to load mysqli.so. Make sure you're editing the file for the Apache instance (`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` if I'm remembering correctly) and not the CLI instance. And of course don't forget to restart the service after any changes!

Comment: I don't think that's the right file. The ini file I've been editing that causes Apache to give errors when it loads PHP is in `/usr/local/lib/php.ini`. I'm pretty sure this is the right file because when I change it my Apache output changes. But the place it's looking for extensions doesn't have the `mysqli.so` file. The only `mysqli.so` file I can find anywhere is `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so`, and pointing `php.ini` to that file just gives the undefined symbol error that I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: The file I mentioned above is the correct file for a package-based install. Your question suggested this is what you're using. However, if you're using /usr/local then some elements of your system must have been manually compiled. If that's the case, you'll need to stop using apt-get and continue building things yourself. You have to pick one strategy or the other, it's not wise to mix; certainly not with something as tightly integrated as Apache and PHP.

Comment: Yeah I realized this eventually... I ended up just wiping my box because it was such a mess and started fresh only using apt-get. Works like a charm now!